# Macro giving different values for different compilers

Tags: c++

On gcc-4.8.5

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#define CONVERT(a, str) (sprintf(str , "%llu", a))

int main()
{
    char str[10];
    CONVERT(10, str);

    cout<<"  Str = "<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output - `Str = 10`

But the same code on DevC++ prints some junk value (always same). Not able to find the issue.[image]

EDIT :- If i do - `CONVERT((unsigned long long)10, str);` - it works fine.
But still question remains? Why this difference between these two compilers? Just there implementaion or something hidden in this?

Comment: Which is why when writing C++ code one should really write type-safe C++ code, that uses the `<<` operator, instead of crufty C code that uses C library functions.

Comment: "Why this difference between these two compilers?" Undefined behaviour is undefined by definition...